# Error: while writing pyspark dataframe into Habse

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write the pyspark dataframe into Hbase. Facing below error.

Spark and Hbase version on my cluster are:

Spark Version: 2.4.0
Hbase Version: 1.4.8

Spark Submit

```
 spark-submit --jars /tmp/hbase-spark-1.0.0.jar   --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ --files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml to_hbase.py
```

error:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem - using spark-habse-connector (shc) with spark2.4.
There is a fix @dhananjay_patka did.

Check: [SHC With spark 2.4](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/SHC-on-HDP-3-0-With-spark-2-4/td-p/236356) 
and [his fix](https://github.com/dhananjaypatkar/shc)